# C++: Placement new collides with own new overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, placement-new

I have overloaded the new operator for a type `X` to use some memory pool. My `new` operator takes no user-defined arguments, thus, the only argument is the size of the object of type `size_t`. At another part of the program, I need placement new for the same type, like this:

```
new (ptr) X();
```

(where ptr is a pointer to a preallocated memory location)

It seems that my overload of the new operator for the type shadows placement new. At least, the compiler complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘X::operator new(long unsigned int, X*&)’
note: candidate is:
note: static void* X::operator new(size_t)
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

The candidate is my overload of the new operator. My questions are:

- Why doesn't the compiler recognize that I want to use placement new?
- How can I use it anyway?
- WTF is the type `X*&` shown in the error message?

Comment: X*& is reference to X*. To return X* via argument. http://codepad.org/7vu3r04b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding TypeName::operator new (size_t) requires you to also override the placement new operator (the opposite is not required). That's why the compiler is complaining. (Makes sense - if you're doing something strange during allocation, you might want to do that at the specified place in the placement new operator as well, with the reverse not necessarily true).
And X*& is just a reference to the pointer where you want the new object.

Comment: but why a reference to the pointer and not the pointer itself?

Comment: @gexicide: because the parameter is an lvalue its type will be deduced to reference.

Comment: Can you provide a reason/quote as to why this is the case?

Comment: Good question - I'd love to know too. l- and r-values have become somewhat of a buzz-word since c++11. I also tried a simple test and it seems msvc2010 isn't complaining about the missing placement new override, nor does it define the global placement new with a reference argument. Weird...